# Executing array string as JS method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code.
How can I execute the the clearSearch method as part of the methods Array?

```
//Assume this is in a different file, inside a controller. 
//I have access to the controller through a global variable.

function clearSearch() {
    console.log('Search cleared');
}
```

.

```
function Task() {
    this.controllers = [];
    this.stores = [];
    this.methods = [];
}

var taskList = [];

var task = new Task();
task.controllers.push('Search');
task.stores.push('search.Case', 'search.Result');
task.methods.push('clearSearch');

taskList.push(task);
```

Comment: Which `clearSearch` method? Where is it defined?

Comment: You do realize you're pushing strings, right, not methods?

Comment: I realize I'm pushing Strings, it's why I'm asking this question in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the function in your scope:

```
function clearSearch() { ... }
```

Then you should reference it by name not by the string and push that:

```
task.methods.push(clearSearch);
```

To execute it you can do now:

```
task.methods[i]();
```

Where `i` is the index of the desired function in the array.

Comment: OK, however it is not in the scope, it's under a controller in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `clearSearch` function in an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    clearSearch: function () {
        console.log('Search cleared');
    }
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
obj['clearSearch']();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/N6rgQ/)**

See this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) on bracket notation for more information.